# Different ways to save game saves?

Tags: android

From what I've looked up there are multiple ways to save files (in my case game files). I was wondering what would be the most ideal for saving in the app. There are multiple (5+) game saves that will be needed. I would ideally like to store them as text files. Would I be able to do it with shared pref? Or should I use SQLite or just internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the data structure and the amount of data you want to save.
For example if you need to save some pritive data types like High score, current level, then `SharedPreferences` should be OK.

On the other hand, if you have large amount of data, then perhaps saving them in a file, or database would be more appropriate.

Comment: Well the text files have a name and inside them are just text, but it shouldn't get over a 1mb file. If I save them as files would that be the internal storage?

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends HOW you save the file. Here's an example how to save to internal storage: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal